# Datetime conversion from GMT to CST

Tags: apex, datetime

Can someone please provide the code of converting the GMT timezone to CST.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
system.debug('>>>' + now);
Long offset = DateTime.newInstance(now.date(), now.time()).getTime()
- DateTime.newInstance(now.dateGmt(), now.timeGmt()).getTime();
 system.debug('>>offset' + offset);
Datetime local = now.addSeconds(offset/1000);
system.debug('@@@@' + local);
```

I have tried the above logic and i require the CST hour and minutes.

It is throwing the below error for me.

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void addSeconds(Long) from the type Datetime

Comment: We would love to help you but as an author of question please spend time explaining what you attempted ,put sample code and show where you are blocked .

Comment: this is a bit annoying as you posted essentially the same question twice and I spent time answering one before discovering this second question

Comment: DateTime dtGmt = DateTime.now();
system.debug('***********This will retun current CST time ******' + dtGmt.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss','America/Chicago');

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Timezone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_timezone.htm) method for this

```
// Get the CST time zone
Timezone tz = Timezone.getTimeZone('America/Chicago');
integer offset = tz.getOffset(System.now());
system.debug(tz.getOffset(System.now()));   //offset value in milliseconds
Datetime cstDatetime = System.now().addSeconds(offset/1000);
```

If you want to get TimeZone Sid key dynamically based on users time zone configured in the user record in salesforce use the below

```
// Get the CST time zone
Timezone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
integer offset = tz.getOffset(system.now());
system.debug(tz.getOffset(system.now()));   //offset value in milliseconds
Datetime cstDatetime = System.now().addSeconds(offset/1000);
```

Notice how i get the offset of type integer using the TimeZone key and then one can add seconds to the Datetime variable .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87980/discussion-between-user5558-and-mohith-shrivastava).